# Refactoring a Dictionary, changing key type

Tags: c#, refactoring

I am refactoring a C# library that uses a `Dictionary<int, SomeInterface>` all over the system.
I need to change the key type from int to string, and use a `Dictionary<string, SomeInterface>` instead, and I am making dozens of changes.
How to do it better, how to define a type in one place and uses it everywhere, so that if I need to change it later, I can change it in one place?

I already added a GetKey() method to my interface.

Edit: the library is used in other DLLs, and I want to limit possible changes to only one library. This is an agile shop, so we need to be ready for changes.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty serious change, like something that requires reworking of some logic anyway.

Comment: Do you really expect to change the key type that often?  Don't over engineer!

Comment: Sometimes I'm left scratching my head...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If swapping the type of key is important to you, consider a custom class wrapping the underlying key.

e.g, `public class Key { public Key(object adaptee) { ... } }`

Remember to implement Equals() and GetHashCode() and just delegate to the underlying object.

I'm not sure if this helps your particular scenario, but in general, Resharper is a fantastic tool to help assist with these types of changes.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I am using Resharper, which just generated some of this code for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create you own keyType that is:

- a struct

  - contains a int field
  - has converter to/from int (marked as obsolete)
  - has GetHashCode() and Equal() methods that call the methods on the field
- Start to use the keyType
- Use the obsolete complier warning to guid you
- Once all the Dictionarys are using the new keyType and you are getting no more obslete warning, then convert the type of the field inside of keyType

Comment: what is this "obsolete complier warning"? I don't seem to get any.

Comment: @Arne, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx thing of it as a way to get the compiler to tell you everywhere a methed is being used without breaking the build.

Comment: Resharper shows me all the usages. It think it is easier to use it, unless I am missing something. Thanks!